# getBBox() missing values on text elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, raphael, jsdom

I have a Node.js project which uses jsdom and Raphael Js to generate SVG markup on my server, all was going well until I started to get missing values when calling getBBox() on Raphael text elements.

```
var paper = window.Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
var txt = paper.text(10, 10, 'hello world!');       
console.log( txt.getBBox().toString() ); // Returns: NaN NaN NaN × NaN
```

whereas ...

```
var rect = paper.rect(10, 10, 10, 10);
console.log( rect.getBBox().toString() ); // Returns: 10 10 10 × 10
```

What would be the cause of this and more importantly is there a fix?

Comment: Can you try a JSFiddle of your code? I gave this a whirl and it works as expected: [http://jsfiddle.net/hardwickj/JHqxw/](http://jsfiddle.net/hardwickj/JHqxw/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `print()` method of RaphaelJs, which produces an array of paths. You can use `getBBox()` on the array to get the bounding box.

Answer (score 1):

TextElement.getBBox() only work in browsers, it should not be used in server side.